# Flutter Dart Search List

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
List<String> topics = [
  'Photography',
  'News',
  'Facts',
  'How-to',
  'Technology',
  'Science',
  'Space',
];
```

I have a list of about 70-80 words. I want to search this list and make it searchable even if a spelling mistake is made. The list is also **case-sensitive**. No UI needed.
How can I do it in ***Flutter***/***Dart***?

For example if I type 'tec', the `Techonology` topic should be the result. The topics are case sensitive, but the query should handle this too.

Comment: You need to specify a lot more requirements and come with some examples. What do you define as "spelling mistake" (are e.g. case problems also spelling mistakes)? Should the code come with multiple candidates for words which could be correct? What have you done to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you taken a look at: https://www.google.com/search?q=search+through+a+list+flutter ? The list cannot be searchable even if there is a spelling mistake. For that you would have to use a search engine like algolia or elasticsearch. I would personally not implement the searching even if there is a spelling mistake because it is expensive to use the above search engines.

Comment: This might be hepful https://blog.usejournal.com/flutter-search-in-listview-1ffa40956685

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below one

```
List<String> topics = [
  'Photography',
  'News',
  'Facts',
  'How-to',
  'Technology',
  'Science',
  'Space',
];
  
 var text='ence';
 var _searchResult = topics.where(
                    (topics) => (topics.contains(text) || 
                    topics.toLowerCase().contains(text))
                );
  
 print(_searchResult.toString());
```